# Simple script to clean file names

Tags: regex, linux, bash, filenames

I've got the following "problem". I have a bunch of files (like thousands) named "ThisIsAFile-BLAH.txt", and I would like to clean these file names so that they're called only "ThisIsAFile.txt", removing everything after the "-" symbol including it.

What would be the best way to proceed?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

P.S.
OS is GNU/Linux.
P.S. 2
I'm trying to teach myself how to automate menial tasks by writing simple scripts.

Solution:

Thanks guys. I finally got it.

```
rename 's/-[^-]*(?=\.\w+)$//' *.txt
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Check `man rename`, see if supports regex. if it does, something as simple as this would do it

```
rename 's/-.*/.txt/' *.txt
```

That searches all .txt filenames for a dash, and replaces it and everything that follows with .txt

Answer (score 1):

Let's say:

```
s="ThisIsAFile-BLAH.txt"
```

Pure BASH:

```
echo "${s/-*\./.}"
ThisIsAFile.txt
```

Using sed:

```
sed 's/-.*\./\./' <<< "$s"
ThisIsAFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

by using awk it can be written as

input file:

```
ThisIsAFile2-Blah.txt
ThisIsAFile3-Blah.txt
ThisIsAFile-Blah.txt
```

command for changing

```
ls *.txt|awk `s=$1` 'BEGIN{FS="-"; OFS=""} {print "mv "$s" "$1,".txt"}' |sh
```

output of the same would be

```
 ThisIsAFile2.txt
 ThisIsAFile3.txt
 ThisIsAFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many files, you can loop through your files with a glob:

```
for i in *-BLAH.txt; do
    mv -nv -- "$i" "${i%-BLAH.txt}.txt"
done
```

(note the use of `-n` so as to not overwrite an otherwise already existing file, the use of `-v` so at to be verbose (optional) and the use of `--` just in case one file starts with a hyphen, so as to not confuse `mv` that would try to interpret it as options). Also not the quotings!

If you have lot of files, you can use `find`, it might be quicker than Bash's globbing:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*-BLAH.txt' -exec bash -c 'while(($#)); do mv -nv -- "$1" "${1%-BLAH.txt}"; shift; done' _ {} +
```

Here I'm using *find*'s `+` operator so that the `bash` command is not spawned too many times. Then *bash* does its loop on the arguments given by *find*. Note the use of the dummy argument `_` since launched this way, *Bash* will set its positional arguments starting from 0, not from 1.

The *find* method is really good, as you can fine tune which files will you'll apply the *bash* loop to. Inside the *bash* loop, you can then generate whatever renaming scheme you like.